# Build Next.js : Error occurred prerendering page "/api/user"

Tags: javascript, next.js

When I build my `Next.js 14` app with `app directory`, I get :

```
[Error]: Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `headers`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error
    at l (/Users/joh/Documents/dev/waletoo/.next/server/chunks/185.js:30:30275)
    at u (/Users/joh/Documents/dev/waletoo/.next/server/chunks/185.js:30:26794)
    at s (/Users/joh/Documents/dev/waletoo/.next/server/chunks/185.js:30:20357)
    at p (/Users/joh/Documents/dev/waletoo/.next/server/app/api/user/route.js:1:1271)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/joh/Documents/dev/waletoo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:41304 {
  digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/api/user". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Internal Server Error
    at p (/Users/joh/Documents/dev/waletoo/.next/server/app/api/user/route.js:1:1442)
```

Here is how I manage my `api/user/route` route :

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import connectDB from "@/src/mongoDB/connect";
import UserModel from "@/src/mongoDB/userSchema";
import { authOptions } from "@/src/utils/authOptions";

export async function GET() {
    await connectDB();

    try {
        const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

        if (!session?.user?.email) throw new Error("Unauthorized");

        const userEmail = session.user.email;
        const userInformations = await UserModel.find({ email: userEmail });

        return new Response(JSON.stringify(userInformations));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error("Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you’re seeing is due to the use of getServerSession in a statically generated page. In Next.js, server rendering usually happens in one place, so fetching data associated with a user needs to be known to be dynamic.

To resolve this issue, you can add export const dynamic = "force-dynamic" at the top of your page. This tells Next.js that the page has dynamic server usage and cannot be statically optimized. Here’s how you can modify your cod

Javascript:

```
   export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import connectDB from "@/src/mongoDB/connect";
import UserModel from "@/src/mongoDB/userSchema";
import { authOptions } from "@/src/utils/authOptions";

export async function GET() {
    await connectDB();

    try {
        const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

        if (!session?.user?.email) throw new Error("Unauthorized");

        const userEmail = session.user.email;
        const userInformations = await UserModel.find({ email: userEmail });

        return new Response(JSON.stringify(userInformations));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error("Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```